# How to show JSON on a page and also read a particular value from it

Tags: javascript, json, ajax

I would like my code to get JSON and read the temperature value for London.

Any help would be very appreciated.

However I have two issues, the data fetched shows this: [object Object]

1. How to repair it?
2. How to make it fetch the temperature value for London, which is in main and temp.

Maybe like this:

```
data.["main"].temp
```

It's a Kelvin temperature for London, 277.21.

My JSON:

```
{
    "coord": { "lon": -0.1257, "lat": 51.5085 },
    "weather": [{ "id": 800, "main": "Clear", "description": "clear sky", "icon": "01n" }],
    "base": "stations",
    "main": { "temp": 277.21, "feels_like": 275.36, "temp_min": 274.4, "temp_max": 279.13, "pressure": 1042, "humidity": 93 },
    "visibility": 9000,
    "wind": { "speed": 2.06, "deg": 230 },
    "clouds": { "all": 9 },
    "dt": 1642014889,
    "sys": { "type": 2, "id": 2019646, "country": "GB", "sunrise": 1641974505, "sunset": 1642004119 },
    "timezone": 0,
    "id": 2643743,
    "name": "London",
    "cod": 200
}
```

My bad code:

```
 $.ajax({
            url: "https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=London&appid=a7a01852c805157a4c8334e87e39c75c",
            cache: false,
            dataType: "json",
            complete: function(data) {
               

                tempLondon = data;
             
                 $('#tempLondon').append('The temperature is ' + tempLondon );
                 console.log(tempLondon);
            }
        });
```

Comment: Don't mix dot and bracket notations (it doesn't work like that). `data["main"].temp`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
$.ajax({
type: 'GET',
url: "https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=London&appid=a7a01852c805157a4c8334e87e39c75c",
dataType: "json",
success: function(data) {

console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
$('#tempLondon').html('The temperature is ' + data.main.temp );
 
},
error: function (error) {
console.log(JSON.stringify(error));
}     
  });
```

in the future don't put dot and brackets together.

it is valid

```
 data.main.temp
//or 
data["main"].temp
```

it is NOT valid

```
data.["main"].temp
```

Comment: Thank you! However there is still an issue. This code: ```data.main.temp``` results in undefined.

Comment: @Marcin  Sorry , I didn't know that you can not get any data.I updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

When you convert an object to a string, for example by trying to insert it directly into markup, it gets turned into `'[object Object]'`. While this is certainly unintuitive, you have to remember that objects can contain circular references so it may not be possible to convert them to strings.

However, you can instead use `JSON.stringify` to convert your object to a JSON string and print that to the console instead:

```
console.log(JSON.stringify(tempLondon, null, '\t'));
```

Because your object is constructed from a JSON string in the first place (this happens behind the scenes in jQuery's `$.ajax` function), it can't contain any circular references so there won't be any problem constructing a JSON string from it.

If you want to retrieve the temperature itself, just use dot notation:

```
console.log(tempLondon.main.temp);
```

Comment: Thank you! The log of JSON worked. However the reading of ```tempLondon.main.temp``` results in: TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'tempLondon.main.temp')

Comment: In that case it sounds like the object you're getting doesn't match the one you've pasted in the question. If it's possible that the temperature is not being returned, you will need code to handle that case. Depending on what browsers you need to support, you may be able to use [optional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) (e.g. `tempLondon?.main?.temp)` otherwise you'll want to use either `if` or `&&` to ensure each level exists before looking any deeper (for example `tempLondon && tempLondon.main && tempLondon.main.temp`)